# What base resolution to design for with Android?

Tags: android, photoshop, screen-resolution

I am new to designing interfaces for Android. (I have gone through the Multiple Screens section in the Developer Guide.) What base resolution are you designing your screens for?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

That is based on your app is for phone, or tablet, or both. Currently when designing layout for phone's app, there are three most basic resolution: 

 - 320dip x 480dip (normally 320px x 480px phone)

 - 320dip x 533dip (normally 480px x 800px phone)

 - 320dip x 569dip (normally 480px x 854px phone)

So when you design layout for phone's app, please remember:

1. Always use dip for width, height and sp for text size

2. A layout fit 320dip x 480dip screen will fit the other two

3. match_parent, wrap_content, gravity... are powerful Android XML layout attributes

4. Choose the orientation (landscape, portrait) carefully, normally an app requires only one orientation

The same goes for tablet's app, choose the most normal screens and create layout for the smallest one, and stretch the layout on bigger one.

But for both tablet and phone, you should use dimens.xml to store layout values. Reference here: http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/resources/more-resources.html#Dimension

Good luck with Android nightmare :)

Comment: suppose i wanted to support something like an S3...how would I go about doing it? which is the base resolution i should use/

Comment: @Hades As I said, the smallest layout will also fit the bigger. You should create layout for your smallest devices which you aim then stretch it out.

Comment: sorry if i'm being a pain, so ideally I would have a 320x533 screen and then scale it upwards? but then the images might get pixelated right? can't I design for something like 640x960 and then resize it? can I use a single resolution? to support all?

Comment: @Hades There's no perfect way for Android resolution problem. The fastest way is to stretch the layout, but, for example if your layout use an image as background, there are chances the width and height of image will not be in the right ratio on some devices. A more painful way is to design for every resolution you want to support, and store all resources (images, dimension, etc.) in your app (which make your app much more bigger). You can see the link at the end of my answer for specific details.

Answer (score 2):

Dont design for specific screen resolution!

Design for a range of devices either small screen, Medium screen or large screen.

Following are generic irrespective of your screen size.
Best layout is LinearLayout and RelativeLayout.
Bes metrics for Views 'dp' and for fonts 'sp'

Hope this helps!

Comment: If its the case Anh Tuan has answered you appropriately!

Answer (score 1):

I recommend base resolution for 320x480 pixel screen as this is supported by most number of devices. But you need to provide assets for hdpi (High Density), mdpi (medium density), ldpi (low density), xhdpi (xtra high density) specially images, buttons etc.